# get maximum date in separated columns (month and year)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table :

```
Month   Year    Provider    Number
1       2015    1           345
2       2015    1           345
3       2015    1           345
12      2015    2           444
1       2016    2           444
```

Let's say I want to get all different numbers by provider but only the max month and max year, something like this:

```
Month   Year    Provider    Number
3       2015    1           345
1       2016    2           444
```

I have this ugly query that I would like to improve :

```
SELECT (SELECT max([Month]) 
        FROM dbo.Info b
        WHERE b.Provider = a.Provider
          AND b.Number = a.Number
          AND [Year] = (SELECT max([Year]) 
                          FROM dbo.Info c
                         WHERE c.Provider = a.Provider
                           AND c.Number = a.Number)) AS [Month],
        (SELECT max([Year]) 
           FROM dbo.Info d
          WHERE d.Provider = a.Provider
            AND d.Number = a.Number)) AS [Year],
        a.Provider,
        a.Number
 FROM dbo.Info a
```

Comment: Is there a problem with your query?

Comment: If at all possible I would highly recommend storing date time information in a single datetime column. Storing this in two columns is very challenging. Of course this isn't always possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a row_number and cte

```
;WITH cte AS (
  SELECT 
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Provider ORDER BY [Year] DESC, [Month] DESC) as rNum
  FROM Info)

SELECT *
FROM cte where rNum = 1
```

If you want to create a view then

```
CREATE VIEW SomeViewName
AS

WITH cte AS (
  SELECT 
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Provider ORDER BY [Year] DESC, [Month] DESC) as rNum
  FROM Info)

SELECT *
FROM cte where rNum = 1
```

Comment: ok let's say I need a view and I want to use this, I should create an inline function I guess, in that case performance is still good?

Comment: You can create a view with a cte. No need for inline function.

Comment: @carlosm Added how to create a view with cte.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `row_number`:

```
select *
from (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by provider 
                                 order by [year] desc, [month] desc) rn
    from dbo.Info
) t
where rn = 1
```

This assumes the number and provider fields are the same.  If not, you may need to also partition by the number field.